# pass dll stdout to java console

Tags: java, c++, dll, output

I use a dll, programmed in c++, which has some outputs via cout or printf. In my Java Application I load this dll via JNA. Now I have both a Java Applet and a Java Web Start Application. For debugging (java programme ends as dll ends) I want to read the output from dll, but I don't get any output within java console. 
How can I get the output in java console, file, command line, where- and whatever? I'm sorry, but I'm not a c++ expert, more a newbie.

**EDIT 1:**
Let me explain it in more detail and with an example:

The code for DLL file

PrintString.h

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdint.h>

using namespace std;

namespace JNATEST
{
    class debugging
    {
    public:
        static __declspec(dllexport) void getString();
    };
}
```

PrintString.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "PrintString.h"

using namespace JNATEST;
using namespace std;

void debugging::getString()
{
    cout << "test" << endl;
    printf( "hello" );
}
```

Than the Java Code is the following:
jna interface DLLMapping.java:

```
public interface DLLMapping extends Library{
    public void getString();
}
```

main java programme:

```
public class JNATest{
    static{
        // load path to jna.library.path
        System.setProperty("jna.library.path", (System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")));
        // unzip dll to that path
        .... (not important for that case)
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DLLMapping clib = (DLLMapping)Native.loadLibrary("PrintString", DLLMapping.class);
        clib.getString();
    }
}
```

My problem is now, that everything works fine as far as I try it within eclipse. But when I use it as applet or jnlp, than I see that everything is loaded but I don't get any result to java console. My question is now why?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What DLL is it? Example code? Is there output coming from SOMEWHERE? Does this work for you http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access#Example ?

Comment: were you able to get this to work? I'm having the same issue myself